# How to properly set text direction attribute = RTL for the entire app using bootstrap rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, right-to-left

I am learning to use bootstrap gem 4.2.1 with rails 5.2.2, and facing some difficulty understanding on how to set the direction of content for the entire rails app to be Right to Left.

First two lines of my file `app/views/layout/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ur" dir="rtl">
```

nicely flip the bootstrap `nav`.

other `html` elements such as `h1` continue to display content right to left unless I override the style in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` as shown below

```
 p{
    font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq';
    src:asset-url('JameelNooriNastaleeq.ttf') format("truetype");
    float:right;
    direction: rtl;

}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq';
    src:asset-url('JameelNooriNastaleeq.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```

`p` tags  render the contents as desired from right to left. All other tags such as `h1` render contents from left to right.

My question is how can I set the direction of contents right to left for the entire rails app?

Entire code of my rails app is available on [github](https://github.com/beyond2013/trybs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the Bootstrap library overrides the behaviour that you are setting in the `<html>` tag with the `rtl` attribute.

On their github repo it says that they [don't support RTL as of now.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19555). So the recommended approach is to use customized bootstrap library with RTL support like this one: [bootstrap-rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl).

The only thing that might be a problem in your specific situation is that you use Bootstrap 4.2 and I'm not sure if bootstrap-rtl supports all 4.2 features since it's for 3.X.